# Disable specific compiler optimization

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-construction

I have the following test-code compiled on Win7's MinGW's gcc using C::B:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Func. prototype */
char* returnString (void *str);

int main()
{
    printf("%s", returnString("Hello World!!!!!!!!!!!!"));

    return 1;
}

char* returnString (void *str)
{
    char *local = malloc(strlen((char*)str));

    strcpy(local, (char*)str);

    return local;
}
```

By default the allocation would cause a leak/u/b.. because i have to allocate one free byte `+1` where the null terminator would be located. But instead of causing a leak or crash it works like null-terminated. Is there any way to dissable this?
..instead of going through 5543 lines of code where `+1` is used.

Comment: What does this have to do with compiler optimizations? Anyway, just find each malloc call in your code with *grep* or *Find in files...* of editor, and check and fix. There can't be more than a few dozen of them, so a few minutes of work.

Comment: If you wonder why it crashes rarely: `malloc` allicates at even 8 or 16 or something like that bytes. So most of the time there are a few unused bytes between allocations, so missing +1 will have no effect, except for every string with length divisible by some number. Really nasty to debug without valgrind or allocation guard bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line below causes a *buffer overflow* because of the missing `+ 1` when the size to allocate was previously computed.

```
    strcpy(local, (char*)str);
```

A buffer overflow is much more serious than a memory leak. Unfortunately, a buffer overflow does not systematically crashes the program. It invokes *undefined behavior*, meaning that anything can happen, including the program continuing as if you had allocated a large enough bloc. This is not a compiler optimization: it can happen (or not) at any optimization level, and the programmer has very little control over what happens. See below for some partial solutions.

---

One way to obtain diagnostic messages for many buffer overflows is to use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to execute the program after having compiled it normally.

Alternately, recent versions of Clang and GCC incorporate an “address sanitizer” feature, activated with `-fsanitize=address`, that inserts in the generated code some instructions that may detect the problem. I haven't used this feature but documentation is [available](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/).

Comment: The poster's code actually causes a buffer overflow and a memory leak.

Comment: For me it causes nothing. Just prints out the text. It has to be an optimization i have to dissable.

Comment: @Edenia A buffer overflow in C is undefined behavior. It does not have to cause a crash. Not causing a crash is not an optimization, it is just bad luck. There is no simple option that you can use to tell GCC to generate a program that crashes on all undefined behaviors, but see if the address sanitizer feature is what you are looking for (`-fsanitize=address` for GCC 4.8 or later).

Comment: I know it should cause an buffer overflow. But thought there is an indication for it. No i think i can use `errno.h` for that. To indicate if that happans.

Comment: @Edenia what do you mean "no indication of that"? Buffer overflows are a silent error that are generally only detected (as what they are) when you're in an environment such as valgrind that is testing for it. Otherwise it **can** show up as some unexpected behavior in your program (**possibly** including a seemingly unrelated crash).

Comment: Thats what i meant by indication. It is from a large large program, with a lot of used allocations like that (without `+1`) i am 100% sure that the program can't work correct. Thats why i asked for a way to add the `+1` fastly.. because elseway i have to go through 5k lines.
No idea why the program works like that.

Comment: Updated my comment to indicate that it is not guaranteed that it will show up at all. It is **completely undefined** what will happen. Your program could run fine 999/1000 times, you could never see an error, or you could always see one.

Comment: So just its bad made program and i have to fix a lot..
Bad to know its not an optimization. But still working program after like 50 stack overflows.... it works within GTK+

Comment: @Edenia [**buffer** overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) not stack overflow, big difference. You should probably read up on exactly what a buffer overflow is if you're tasked with fixing it. Also note you could avoid this issue by using [strncpy](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.14.html#strncpy) instead where possible.

Comment: @sharth Oh, right, because the function call is directly used as argument of `printf()`. I agree that if there wasn't undefined behavior, there would be a memory leak, then. I'm an author of one of the two articles I referred to (but the article was peer-reviewed, it not just me ranting), and the other article is “Challenges in Comparing Software Verification Tools for C”, submitted independently with much of the same ideas.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Yeah. That was the point I was (very poorly) trying to get at. If we increase the function stack so that the call to the `returnString()` function isn't in `main()`, then we can get valgrind to report memory as actually being lost: https://gist.github.com/sharth/c6f78a4937cdcab86d62 I'll take a look at the two papers as well.

Comment: @sharth I hope you noted that the URL was http://fmv.jku.at/papers/COMPARE2012Proceedings.pdf because as my first comment was misinformed, I am deleting it.